# How to get path to CurrentSetting.vssettings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to try to get some properties from the CurentSetting.vssettings file, which located in directory:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_1905b589\Settings

But i dont know what the version of 16.0_1905b589.

I tried to use GetAssymbly... but returned value is = 16.6.0.38

How i can get path to this file or may be get this version (From C#)?

Comment: The filename and path can be changed under "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Import and Export Settings". you can give user defined path as well

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think may be my ask in not correct. Me interesting how i can get this version from code or this path (C#)?

Comment: There may be multiple folders about configuration under "VisualStudio", so I think you have to use the absolute path to access "Setting".